# 301 redirects redirecting not the specified link

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

want to redirect some links from oldsite to new one and doing like this:

```
Redirect 301 /benefits  http://newsite.com/our-differiantiators/
Redirect 301 /benefits/our-people http://newsite.com/about-us/
Redirect 301 /benefits/our-places http://newsite.com/infrastucture/
Redirect 301 /benefits/our-platforms    http://newsite.com/infrastucture/
Redirect 301 /benefits/our-experience http://newsite.com/
Redirect 301 /benefits/our-testimonials http://newsite.com/
```

but if i try to go to my `newsite.com/benefits/our-people` it redirecting to `newsite.com/our-differiantiators/our-people` not `newsite.com/about-us`

how should I fix my .htaccess code to redirect like I want?

P.S.
maybe it's because slug `/our-people` and `/our-differiantiators` and wordpress somehow is handling that?

Comment: If you remove the first like, it works OK? Try that (to see what's going on), and then try changing it by this line: `RedirectMatch /benefits$ http://newsite.com/our-differiantiators/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: nope.. it's not working.. it still redirects me to `newsite.com/our-differiantiators/our-people` ... mybe it's because slug `our-people` and `our-differiantiators` and somehow wordpress is handling that?

Comment: @ishegg no [R=301,L] with RedirectMatch it is mod_alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line :

```
Redirect 301 /benefits  http://newsite.com/our-differiantiators/
```

by this :

```
RedirectMatch  301 /benefits/$  http://newsite.com/our-differiantiators/
```

With `RedirectMatch` you will match only `benefits/` ,ended with slash, directory when it comes alone otherwise the other rules will work

Comment: Still nothing.. :/

Answer (score 2):

Try to write: `Redirect 301 /benefits  http://newsite.com/our-differiantiators/` at the end of file;

Or you can change the first line with: 
`RedirectMatch ^/benefits$ http://newsite.com/our-differiantiators/`

Comment: same result as if it is at the top of the file :/

Comment: Remove from the beginning and add at the end. I tried and it works, you saved the .htacceess file?

Comment: nope.. it's not working.. it still redirects me to newsite.com/our-differiantiators/our-people ... mybe it's because slug our-people and our-differiantiators and somehow wordpress is handling that?